# Am I inserting the .pem certficate correctly in my https.request method?

Tags: node.js, authentication, ssl, https, node-https

I'm making a call to an API that requires both a HTTPS Basic Authentication and certification.
The cert has a passphrase. This is my `config` variable:

```
const cert = fs.readFileSync('path.pem');

const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    cert: cert,
    passphrase: '...',
    auth: 'user:pwd',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    }
}
```

When calling the `http.request(url, config, callback)`, I keep on getting this error thrown (on the `'error'` event of the `http.request` object):

```
"errorMessage": "Error: Error: Error: write EPROTO 140627217733568:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1545:SSL alert number 40\n"
```

I've tried `await`-ing the read of the `.pem` file as well. Same thing.

I just need to know that I'm inserting all my authentication correctly. Then I can know that that's not the issue.

Am I putting my HTTPS Basic Authentication and certification with passphrase in correctly?

Tried making secure call to API, expected normal result, got SSL handshake error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the certificate in the `cert` field is not enough for a mutual TLS connection. You should have a `pem` file which also contains a private key. You should then add a `key` option to your `config` and pass the contents of the `pem` file that contains the private key. I think this should be enough, but there might be some other settings that you might have to tweak to make it work though.